# mask and save a bitmap only one time if the bitmap is already saved in my string path C# .Net

Tags: c#, string, bitmap, byte

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(profileImage))
{
    try
    {
        string logoAddress = profileImage.Remove(0, profileImage.LastIndexOf('/') + 1);
        logoAddress = PathW + @"Content\generate\exitlogo\" + logoAddress;
        bool fileExists = File.Exists(logoAddress);
        byte[] imageBytes = fileExists ? File.ReadAllBytes(logoAddress) : webClient.DownloadData(profileImage);
        if (!fileExists)
            File.WriteAllBytes(logoAddress, imageBytes);

        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes);
        Bitmap OrgImg = new Bitmap(ms);

        NewImg = new Bitmap(OrgImg.Width, OrgImg.Height);
        for (int y = 0; y <= OrgImg.Height - 1; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x <= OrgImg.Width - 1; x++)
            {
                if ((Math.Pow(x - (OrgImg.Width / 2), 2) + Math.Pow(y - (OrgImg.Width / 2), 2)) < Math.Pow(OrgImg.Width / 2, 2))
                    NewImg.SetPixel(x, y, Color.FromArgb(255, OrgImg.GetPixel(x, y).R, OrgImg.GetPixel(x, y).G, OrgImg.GetPixel(x, y).B));

                else
                    NewImg.SetPixel(x, y, Color.Empty);
            }
        }
        logoAddress = logoAddress.Replace(".png", "rounded.png");
        NewImg.Save(logoAddress);
        NewImgsample = PdfImage.FromFile(logoAddress);

        ms.Dispose();
        NewImg.Dispose();
        foreach (PdfPage page in doc.Pages)
        {
            page.Graphics.DrawImage(NewImgsample, 686.211f, 247.0f, 101.389f, 101.389f);
        }
    }
    catch
    {

    }
}
```

Hi
I am trying to save a bitmap first in to a path from data, then that saved pic need to be masked first and then save it with different extension.
I need to mask only if the pic is not already masked. now my code is saved a bit map from database if its not saved it is going to save it , then after save it mask another bitmap and then saved the new bitmap.
I only need to mask one time, how can I check if this image is already masked ? 
this code mask my image each time even if the masked image is already there.
my code is :

Comment: You can use one `bool` variable, check whether it’s value is `false` and then set it to `true`

Comment: or you can use `if(!File.Exists(path)) ...`

Comment: I used both bool and if(!File.Exists(path) when I saved the image through Database, but this time at the end of code when i masked the imaged, i saved with "rounded.png" instead, this "rounded.png" saved .  i can not developed these two ways for loading back the 2d image.  i only need this loop will do when the rounded image is not in the path    .....

Comment: check this one i mean  logoAddress = logoAddress.Replace(".png", "rounded.png");
        NewImg.Save(logoAddress);
        NewImgsample = PdfImage.FromFile(logoAddress);

Comment: the point is i first masked the image then save it, that the reason file.Exists and bool can not worked